# Semicolons after ages

Tags: punctuation

Would a comma or semicolon correctly follow the word "Florida" below? I used the comma for the last city-state entry. Is this correct?

> Mike Jones, 45, of Lincoln, Nebraska; Sandra Stevens, 42, of Memphis, Tennessee; and Rupert Falcone, 35, of Tallahassee, Florida, were arrested on charges of conspiracy and fraud.

And does a comma--instead of a semicolon--correctly follow "51" below?

> John Smith, 25; Frank Jones, 44; and Amy Horowitz, 51, were all involved in the fraud.

Comment: This is correct. You should use semicolons to separate items in a list that themselves contain commas.

Answer (score 3):

This use of the semicolon is as a *list separator* when the items contained in the list themselves contain commas.  (See [GrammarBook](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/semicolons.asp) rule 4 for semicolons.). For example, a list might read "lions, tigers, and bears" where the "," commas separate the list.  But if the items in the list contain commas, then a semicolon is permitted as the delimiter.  For example "New York, NY; Los Angeles, CA; and Boston, MA."

Just as you would not have a comma at the end of the list, you would not put a semicolon after "51."  For example, the correct punctuation is "Sally, Jane, and Anna went to dinner" and not *"Sally, Jane, and Anna, went to dinner."

Answer (score 0):

Every semicolon you used in these examples should be a comma. And every comma you used is correctly used.

In other words, there should be ONLY commas in these sentences. No semicolons are required.

You might say this could lead to some confusion, and you would be right, but it is nevertheless correct. If you intensely felt the need to avoid this confusion, you *might* change the punctuation or the syntax. For example, you *could* put parentheses around the ages, instead of commas. This is not exactly standard usage, but it seems acceptable. You then, however, would still have some debate as to whether you would retain a comma after the parentheses.

No matter what you do, however, I reiterate that semicolons are pretty definitively not correct at any spot in these sentences as written.

Comment: Strange, John.  I've always used semicolons as list separators when the list items contain commas.  I don't have a Chicago manual handy to check, but I'm fairly certain this is a standard use.  Certainly the online sources agree: e.g. http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/semicolons.asp

Comment: Nope, sorry, that just doesn't apply here. You're misinterpreting something about the use of semicolons, and I'm not sure what, but keep this in mind: You can't use a semicolon to separate the subject of a sentence from the verb. That's simply wrong. Try this: "George; and Harry; and Larry went to town." Would you write it that way? Absolutely not. But that is exactly what the example sentences are doing. If I get a chance, I'll try to go into what it is that's misleading you, but I promise you - believe me on this - those semicolons are flat out wrong.

Comment: So is the comma (obviously not the semicolon) correct after '51', yes or no? Or do we omit the comma after '51'? Bo comma after '51', in this case, would look bizarre. Thank you.

Comment: @whippoorwill You need the commas **around** *51* because that's a parenthetical insertion.

Comment: Andrew is correct. As I stated in my original answer, the comma after "51" is correct; you need one prior to it as well. When commas occur in places like your example sentences, it can be _quite_ confusing, admittedly. That's all the more reason to be especially careful about using them correctly. And, as I suggested, you might even want to restructure the whole thing to lessen the use of them.

Comment: I went to your reference (_grammarbook_) to see what was causing the problem, and I found it. Rule 4 describes semicolons as list separators when the list elements involve commas. I consider this usage to be awkward, but it is acceptable to many authorities. The problem here is that the items in your list are the subjects of the sentence, not the objects (as in the Rule 4 example sentence). When you place the list in the position of the subject, I think _that_ grammatical consideration trumps the semicolon-as-list-separator usage; I just can't agree with using the semicolon in that position.

Comment: ALSO: When the list contains elements that use commas ("Memphis, Tennessee"), a semicolon may separate these elements. But I make a distinction between this usage and the "ages" one in your example. "Memphis, Tennessee," is a distinct entity; the two words are linked, and combine to make up the identity of the list item. In "John Smith, 25," the "25" is not part of the thing itself; it's additional adjectival information. Hence a semicolon is inappropriate here. Look at it this way: "John Smith, a 25 year old man, and Frank Jones, a tall man, were involved." You wouldn't use semicolons.

Comment: I was dissatisfied with my own GrammarBook reference (not a site whose authority I am willing to vouch for :-), so when I got to the office I checked the Chicago Manual.  14th Ed'n 5.94 states "when the items in a series are long and complex or involve internal punctuation, they should be separated by semicolons for the sake of clarity," but the examples given show the list either as a direct object as a full-fledged tricolon of clauses. I'm inclined to agree with John that using a semicolon-delimited list as a subject is unwise, but can't find a definitive source prohibiting it.

Comment: Further evidence of the semicolon delimiter abounds (for example, here at Purdue's OWL: http://owl.english.purdue.edu/engagement/index.php?category_id=2&sub_category_id=1&article_id=44).  (They use the same type of example I did, with a list of cities and states.)  But nobody seems willing to *START* a sentence with such a list....